# Monitor running processes debug information in Windows service

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services, monitoring

I am creating a Windows service to monitor specific processes running on my computer. I was able to capture all the running processes that need to be monitored with the following code:

```
List<Process> processlist = Process.GetProcesses().Where(item => item.ProcessName.Equals(processname)).ToList();
```

Now I want to read the debug information of these processes in my service, so I can do something with it.

I actually want to retrieve the information that is shown in Sysinternal DebugView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), so that I can interpret it in my code.

Is this possible?